# Excel Data Validation sometimes fails

Tags: excel

my data validation sometimes fails to validate 'day' cell

> 10/10/1000 = OK
>
> 10/10/2000 = Fail

```
=AND(
  ISNUMBER(MATCH("??/??/????",A1,0)),
  ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", ""), ".", ""), ":", ""), "/", "")+0)
)
```

us you see first I check format (`ISNUMBER MATCH`),

then remove special char (I using such s long SUBSTITUTE because I reuse it in my program)

`+0` to force number format, and check `ISNUMBER`

Edit:

with short one have the same problem

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("??/??/????",A1,0)),ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/", "")+0))
```

I'm developing with `"xlsx-populate": "^1.17.0"`

+I'm complete noob in Excel, so if you have solution please be explicite

Edit:

any way to force cell to be a String?

I can't remove format check because once Excel is filled my program has to read it

Comment: The 10/10/2000 is being 'read' as 36,809 (10-Oct-2000). Improve the data by formatting as text so no true dates exist. Note the default right-alignment of the true dates.

Comment: Are you sure your formula is looling at the correct ranges?

Comment: Excel is converting `10/10/2000` to a date, `10/10/1000` is being left as a string as the "date" would be before the 1900's.  A date is a number, the number of days since `1/1/1900`.  Therefor it is not in the `"??/??/????"` format and the match fails

Comment: any way to force it to be a String? because I have a lot of cell with bizarre date/time format

Comment: remove the isnumber(match()) part.

Comment: Instead of your +0 to force number, I tend to do *1 which also works...